# SOLVED . M2 SSD detected by BIOS but not by OS

Tags: ssd

I have Ubuntu 18.04, I bought Samsung NVME SSD EVO 970 Plus which is detected by BIOS but not by OS. i have tried  sudo df -h , sudo lshw and also through gparted but no response. my laptop is Dell Inspiron 5570

Output of **sudo lsblk**

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
└─sda2   8:2    0   1.8T  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

Comment: Please add output of `sudo lsblk` to your question.

Comment: @vidarlo done. added output of sudo lsblk

Comment: Many Dell need UEFI update & SSD firmware update. And you probably need to change drive to AHCI. Issues often common across models. Bigger difference if Intel or AMD. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2420905 &

Comment: @oldfred i only have ubuntu installed. can anyother linux distro support my ssd? i will switch to that distro then?

Comment: Samsung has bootable ISO for updates. https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/minisite/ssd/download/tools/ Newer Dells can be directly updated from Devices using LVFS for firmware updates
https://fwupd.org/lvfs/devicelist  More info on updating SSD from Linux. https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_state_drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem by switching from **RAID** to **AHCI** in SATA Operations mode in BIOS.